# Reorder items in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I've got `projects` table and each project has `order` field which is an integer.

And I use this field to re-order projects manually in the database basically. On Frontend I'm using `sortable.js` library and after a simple drag and drop, I deserialise an array of projects and it gives me a newly ordered array of `id`s.

After each drop it calls Backend and passes this array. Then on Backend I'm doing something along the lines of

```
$order = 1;
foreach($ids as $id) {
  Project::find($id)->update(['order' => $order++]);
}
```

It works fine at the moment, but the `projects` list will be around 600+ soon (at the moment it's just around 30) and I fear that it will become an issue as the projects list grows. I was wondering what could be an alternate solution to this?

And because the event is fired `onDrop`, some users might find pleasing to move things around and then put them back (there's a nice animation when dropping an item) and they would be firing a lot of unnecessary re-orders basically.

And it HAS to be `onDrop`, just the way the form is set up at the moment.

Should I try to calculate which items have been moved around on FE instead? Any alternatives, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code unnecessarily fetches all projects before updating them. Use this:

```
Project::whereKey($id)->update(['order' => $order++]);
```

If it's not too complicated, only updating the moved projects sounds like a good alternative.